# Calling a second form instance from first form. But when going back to first form, the second form instance doesn't close

Tags: c#, winforms

I am calling a second form instance with a button click from the first form. In that second form, there is a SqlException that fetches an error if username and password from the first form are incorrect. If SqlException finds an error, it closes the second form and opens up back the first form. The problem is that second form stay in memory, and if a user inserts incorrect username and password for 100 times, 100 instances of the second form will stay in memory, and the memory usage is just piling up. I also have a button on the second form that puts you back in the first form, and I think the same thing is also happening there.

My code for switching between forms:

```
       //first form called FormLogin

        public FormLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();     
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                var nextForm = new Form1();
                nextForm.ShowDialog();
                nextForm.Activate();
                nextForm.Show();
            }

        //SqlException in the second form called Form1 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         catch (SqlException ex)
                   {
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    //var backtologin = new FormLogin();
                    //backtologin.Show();
                    //backtologin.Activate();
                    this.Hide();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Incorrect password, or missing permission!");
                    FormLogin login = new FormLogin();

                    login.ShowDialog();
                    login.Activate();

                    this.Close();
                }

    //second form button for going back to the first form
    private void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                FormLogin login2 = new FormLogin();
                login2.ShowDialog();
                login2.Activate();
                this.Close();
            }
```

Comment: `ShowDialog` will wait for the new dialog to close before progressing with the rest of the code. `FormLogin login2 = new FormLogin();` is not the same form as the original, either.

Comment: @Cid There is try, but i did not include it, as it did not seem relevant

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should be calling your second form instance:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    var nextForm = new Form1();
    nextForm.FormClosing += (s,e) => {
        nextForm.Dispose(); // not always needed, but calling it doesn't hurt. It ensures the "nextForm" variable gets disposed, acts just like "using" statement.
        this.Show();
    };
    try{
        nextForm.Show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //manage your exception here
    }


}
```

Avoid using `ShowDialog` in this case, as you may be treating these two forms as two different "things".

Comment: Do i also need to change the code for calling forms on the second form?

Comment: Depends on your needings. Usually you want to call `ShowDialog` when you need to lock the user on that form, so he doesn't interact with the rest of the **open visible forms**

Comment: I have used your code, and changed from *ShowDialog* to *Show*, and it seems to be working, but when i go back to the first form, the input in my textbox for password is still ther, from previous login. And everytime i load my first form, I can still see increase in memory usage, but it is less then before, its about 10mb increase  every time the first form reloads.

Comment: actualy everytime when i load second form from the button1 on first form, memory usage increases a bit, like its storing forms in memory.

Comment: You need to make sure `nextForm` is actually disposing. Put a breakpoint on the `FormClosing` delegate and check if `nextForm.Dispose()` actually ever runs. As for the textboxes, you need fo manually  clear them. Create a `RefreshForm` method where you assign `string.empty` to all of your `TextBox.Text`, and call it on `nextForm.FormClosing` event.

Answer (score 0):

When showing form with `ShowDialog()` you should use `using` clause

```
using(FormLogin login2 = new FormLogin())
{
    login2.ShowDialog();
}
```

This way after closing login2 it will be disposed.